# Suitable 16-bit checksum?

Tags: sha-256, md5, checksum

I am writing a toy<sup>1</sup> transport protocol and I am trying to implement a feature whereby:

- A 16-bit checksum is included in every packet.
- This checksum can be extended to be 48-bit if the data is large, integrity is important, or whatever (creating this mostly for fun).
- This checksum is intended to protect against errors, not a determined attacker.

My initial thought was to use a well known algorithm such as MD5/SHA<sup>2</sup> and simply take the first/last 16/48 bits. This raises a few questions:

1. **What are the consequences of simply taking a "substring" of a checksum? I assume, perhaps naively, that it would just increase the likelihood of a collision.**
2. **Is there any reason to prefer taking the last *x* bits instead of the first *x* bits, or vice versa?**
3. **When truncating a checksum like this, does SHA actually perform any better than MD5? Keeping in mind I am concerned with errors, not attackers.**

[1] *That is to say, I'm creating it for the purpose of learning. So "just use UDP" or "just use TCP" does apply, but that's why I'm not.*

[2] *Maybe use MD5 if it's 16-bit, SHA if it's 48-bit.*

Comment: Since attacks are not a concern, you might want to consider CRCs.  https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/crc/crc32.html has a selection of CRC polynomials, including 16 and 48-bit CRCs.

Comment: I'm kind of inclined to vote to close this question as off-topic, since it's not really about cryptography. You might be better off asking it on [so] or [cs.se].

Comment: CRC's have the nice property in that if the errors are confined to an $n$ bit region (where $n$ is the size of the CRC), they are guaranteed to catch it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the non-cryptographic properties of hash functions.

Comment: I'm _not_ voting to close this question as off-topic, because it is a common inquiry about the applicability of cryptographic primitives that doesn't seem to well-answered elsewhere that comes up high in web search results.  If this is the site where people ask whether MD5 and SHA-1 (on which we are, for all in tents and porpoises, the internet's experts, as adjudicated by El Goog) have a certain property, namely a certain level of error detection capacity, so be it; then the next person to come along with the same question may find this in search results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a 16-bit truncation of MD5 or SHA-1 or SHA-256 or SHAKE128 as a checksum, but it's not a *good* checksum.

Why not?  Let's model them by a *uniform random function* of $t$ bits, which is a reasonable model in this scenario.  In this case, $\Pr[H(x) = h] = 1/2^t$ for any message $x$ and hash $h$, and every $H(x)$ is *independent* for each distinct $x$.  Thus, the probability of *failing* to detect an error $e$ in a message $x$ is $\Pr[H(x + e) = H(x)] = 1/2^t$ for any message $x$ and any error $e$.  This is the best error detection you can hope for from a hash function designed like a random oracle (or close to it, length extensions notwithstanding).

If you [choose a good 16-bit CRC](https://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings-article/dsn/2004/20520145/12OmNzlUKIz) ([preprint](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Ekoopman/roses/dsn04/koopman04_crc_poly_embedded.pdf), [paywall-free](https://sci-hub.se/10.1109/DSN.2004.1311885); [web site](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Ekoopman/crc/)), then you can be *guaranteed*:

- *any* error of odd parity will be detected, provided the generator polynomial has $x + 1$ as a factor;
- *any* burst error of up to 16 bits will be detected, except an error of the generator polynomial itself, provided the generator polynomial does not have $x$ as a factor (*i.e.*, has a nonzero constant term);
- many errors of up to a certain Hamming weights in data words of up to a certain size will be detected.

Cryptographic hash functions designed for random oracle use like MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256, SHAKE128, *etc.*, guarantee none of these.  They're also often much more expensive to compute than error-detecting codes like checksums, because you're paying an extremely high cost for collision resistance which is of no concern for error detection.

> 1. What are the consequences of simply taking a "substring" of a checksum? I assume, perhaps naively, that it would just increase the likelihood of a collision.

Collisions are not relevant here.  The only thing that is relevant is the probability of error detection.  Any substring of MD5 or SHA-1 or SHA-256 or SHAKE128 is as good as any other.

> 2. Is there any reason to prefer taking the last *x* bits instead of the first *x* bits, or vice versa?

No.  If this led to an appreciably different probability of error detection, then that would be a noteworthy result about the hash function.

> 3. When truncating a checksum like this, does SHA actually perform any better than MD5? Keeping in mind I am concerned with errors, not attackers.

No.  They're both bad choices for detecting independent random bit errors.

Comment: So you pointed out what I had liked to ask: When just using a few fits of the result, is it necessary to use SHA-512, or wouldn't "smaller" variants (like SHA-1) be "enough"?

Answer (score 1):

> What are the consequences of simply taking a "substring" of a checksum? I assume, perhaps naively, that it would just increase the likelihood of a collision.

That's correct for cryptographic checksums.

For non-cryptographic checksums it may also destroy properties with regards to finding e.g. single or double bit errors or regional errors (that the cryptographic hashes do not possess).

> Is there any reason to prefer taking the last x bits instead of the first x bits, or vice versa?

No, not when using a hash that operates on bits / bytes / words, where each bit should be as probable depending on the input. This is true for almost all hashes in use; you may want to check hashes that are based on number theory - but in general you would not want to use those in the first place.

It's a non-formal standard to take the leftmost bits / bytes when truncating hashes.

> When truncating a checksum like this, does SHA actually perform any better than MD5? Keeping in mind I am concerned with errors, not attackers.

No, both outputs could be thought of to be pseudo random.

---

As Eugene and poncho indicated in the comments, it is a much better idea to go for a suitable cyclic redundancy check with well specified error detecting capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have found, there is not a way to answer this question in a cryptographic context that will make cryptographers happy.  If you have a cryptographic hash with 16-bits, or even 48-bits, you have limited protection on using the checksum to detect someone forging the data depending on how much data you send.

I would just use [Error Correcting Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_code) as a checksum in the stream and forgo the idea of using the checksum for anything but stream verification and not data integrity.

It's also worth mentioning that hash takes a lot more cycles and complexity than you probably want if you have a simple device.

Comment: I agree that an "old" CRC may do as well as a truncated "new" cryptographic hash. It's the time of "let's do it with a blockchain, so we are state-of-the-art" maybe ;-)